# Volume of a union of triangles

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the points $$A(t) = (t,t^3,t), \, B(t) = (t,t,t), \, C(t) = (0,2t,t)$$ Find the volume of $$\Omega = \bigcup_{t \in [0,1]} T(t)$$ where $T(t)$ is the triangle generated by the three points $A(t), \, B(t), \, C(t)$. If the points are aligned the set $T(t)$ is just assumed to be the empty set.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Something like this is best done as a triple integral.

Comment: Yes, do you know how?

Comment: Looks like $t\in \mathbb R^3$ is also a real number

Answer (score 0):

Consider the vectors $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}.$ Then the area of $\triangle ABC$ is given by $$\frac12 \lvert {\vec{AB} × \vec{AB}}\rvert,$$ where $|\cdot|$ denotes the euclidean norm.

Thus, the volume swept out is given by the integral of the area over $[0,1].$

The computation is rather light. We have that $\vec{AB}=(0,t-t^3,0)$ and $\vec{AC}=(-t,2t-t^3,0),$ so that $\vec{AB} × \vec{AB}=(0,0,t^2-t^4).$ Thus, we have that $$\frac12 \lvert {\vec{AB} × \vec{AB}}\rvert=\frac12 \sqrt{(t^2-t^4)^2}=\frac12 (t^2-t^4),$$ since we're integrating for $t\in [0,1].$ Thus, the volume is given by the $$\frac12\int_0^1{t^2-t^4\mathrm d t}=\frac{1}{15}.$$

Comment: Thanks! But this is not a standard triple integral for the volume, how can I be sure that this can be done?

Comment: @astrobarrel Well, it can be done provided the volume swept out does not intersect itself; here, this is indeed not the case as two vertices of the triangle are always along lines that are not parallel. The third vertex travels along a space cubical parabola. To calculate a triple integral over the determined volume may be tedious since you would need to be able to algebraically define the volume, and then probably perform coordinate transformations. This method seems shorter to me, especially as the volume is defined parametrically. There's just no point in complicating it.